# Is there an alternative to using ResultSet of one statement as format string parameters to execute another statement

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement, postgresql-9.2, psql, callable-statement

PostgreSQL 9.2, jdbc4, and the DBMS is through PgAdmin3.

I need to retrieve some resultset with a statement object which is a callable object with a stored function and then process the types through comparison of those resultset types. After I process them I hope to set some of them as format string arguments for another statement.

This is some pseudocode of sorts for what I want to accomplish. Essentially I want to iteratively add to batch and then do a batch update with a savepoint or rollback and commit those changes after executing that batch.

In addition there are some postgres in stored procedures as a string for jdbc related syntax I am uncertain of as far as using IS NULL, escaping quotes, requiring a semi-colon, etc.

```
String SQL = "UPDATE AdminBoundaries SET \"WIKI_URL\" = ?";
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refcursorfunc() RETURNS refcursor AS '"
        + " DECLARE "
        + "    mycurs refcursor; "
        + " BEGIN "
        + "    OPEN mycurs FOR SELECT \"NAME_5\", \"NAME_4\", \"NAME_3\", \"NAME_2\", \"NAME_1\", \"NAME_0\", \"WIKI_URL\", \"LEVEL_DEPT\" FROM"
        + " AdminBoundaries WHERE \"WIKI_URL\" IN(SELECT \"WIKI_URL\" FROM AdminBoundaries"
        + " GROUP By \"WIKI_URL\" HAVING (count (\"WIKI_URL\") > 1)) ORDER BY \"WIKI_URL\";; "
        + "    RETURN mycurs; "
        + " END;' language plpgsql");

conn.setAutoCommit(false);
CallableStatement funct = conn.prepareCall("{ ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,? = call refcursorfunc()}");
funct.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
funct.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
funct.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
funct.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
funct.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
funct.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
funct.registerOutParameter(7, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
funct.registerOutParameter(8, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
funct.execute(); 
ResultSet results (ResultSet) funct.getObject(1);
while(results.next()){
String base_url = "http://127.0.0.1/mediawiki/index.php/";
String name0 = rs.getString("NAME_0");
String name1 = rs.getString("NAME_1");
String name2 = rs.getString("NAME_2");
String name3 = rs.getString("NAME_3");
String name4 = rs.getString("NAME_4");
String name5 = rs.getString("NAME_5");
String wiki_url = rs.getString("WIKI_URL");
int level = rs.getInt("LEVEL_DEPT");
}
PreparedStatement pstmt = null; 
pstmt = conn.prepare(SQL, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
if(wiki_url.equals(somestring)){
if(name1 == null){
  if(level != 0){
    pstmt.setString(1, somestring + name1);
    pstmt.addBatch();

    if(name2 == null ){

      ...etc.

     }

       }
    //either executeUpdate or executeBatch
    conn.commit()
    pstmt.clearBatch()
    conn.setAutoCommit(true);
 }
```

Is it possible in this case to mix and match prepared statements, callable statements, or statements?

I know you can only have one resultset per statement open until you execute that statement, but how do I keep the resultset's type objects (i.e. getXXX and store it as some data type) to use on another statement if it closes?

This is for an application that will first use a select to retrieve data, then three updates. All three will be batch updates with varying parameters which will iterate through rows of a database, all on separate transactions with commits after each update. Each update will be a separate function.

I was originally thinking about using the resultset of one statement and then using updateXXX and updateRow, but I'm not entirely sure about the efficiency.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "type objects"? Can you show the code in question?

Comment: Could you give a good example or (pseudo)code of what you try to achieve, because I have read your question twice and I have no clue what you want to do.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I've added some pseudocode and slightly further explanation.

Comment: @CraigRinger, I put up some pseudocode that is similar in nature

Comment: I am pretty sure this can easily be solved with a stored procedure (plpgsql function). But there is just too much noise in this question to work through it.